# Deadly force in self defense vs defense of others

Tags: murder, capital-punishment

In [this answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/33231/440) Ephraim quoted the עץ חיים as quoting the רא"ם as saying that a נרדף - someone who is being pursued and could be killed - doesn't have to worry about using non-deadly force if it would be sufficient to prevent the threat (יכול להצילו באחד מאבריו), rather he can just use deadly force. Only in defense of others does that limitation apply.

1. Where is this opinion of the רא"ם?
2. More importantly, how does it reconcile with the Talmud in [Sanhedrin 49a](http://dafyomi.org/index.php?masechta=sanhedrin&daf=49a&go=Go) that Yoav was guilty of murder because he could have used non-deadly force and didn't, to save his own life?

It is true that Tosfos says that he wasn't actually convicted of murder because he wasn't warned, but still the Gemara couldn't bring up the whole rejection of the defense if it wasn't true at all?

Comment: Somewhat similar: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/12897

Comment: My answer there gives opposed opinion to the Re'em