# Because you can not look at the Shekinah?

Tags: see-sight-vision-blind

I wonder why it is forbidden to look at the Shekinah.
I recently [read on websites about the Kabbalah and mystical meaning of the Parsha](http://www.kabbalaonline.org/kabbalah/article_cdo/aid/1292048/jewish/Now-I-Know-You-are-Beautiful-to-Look-At.htm) about how Abraham have seen the Shekinah when he beheld the beauty of Sarah.

I wonder why he did not die, as other tzaddikim also looked and died as was the case of the sons of Aaron, Nadav and Avihu. And why should one die when looking?

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya. It would make your question stronger if you provided the link(s) to where you read that, and source as much as you can of the rest. http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/1714/i-dont-think-were-explaining-sourcing-properly-to-new-users/1715#1715

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/33225/what-was-hevel-abels-sin/33265#33265

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya. Please [edit] to clarify whether you're asking (a) why one dies on seeing the _sh'china_, (b) why Abraham didn't die on seeing the _sh'china_ (considering that one dies on seeing the _sh'china_), or (c) why it's forbidden to look at the _sh'china_. Those seem like three different questions, and your post seems to conflate them. I'm going to close this post to answers until you do that, so that people don't start posting answers that don't actually address what you seek to know. After your edit, it can easily be reopened.

Comment: Actually three questions of fact. May remain as three questions, since all are interlinked?